# Damaged BIOS after enabling Windows 10 WHQL

Tags: windows-10, bios

I opened the BIOS on an MSI motherboard and enabled the Windows 10 WHQL option, and then I clicked on Save and Reboot. After that, my computer only boots into a jumbled BIOS that I can only explore for a few seconds before it freezes, and it also freezes as soon as I choose any option, and there's no way for me to get into Windows 10. I am unsure of the motherboard model, but the screen shows this code: E7A15IMS.100.

Comment: Normally, freezing in BIOS has nothing to do with enabling WHQL signature verification. You could try to reset your BIOS options by removing the battery in the MotherBoard.

Comment: Exactly how do I remove it? What tools do I need? (It's a desktop computer)

Comment: Nevermind, already found out how. I will attempt it when I have the chance.

Comment: @AlexGallegos - Instead of telling us you solved this problem in a comment. You should submit a comment, after you verified it worked, and then delete the comment.

Comment: @Ramhound The problem is not fixed yet, I meant to say that I figured out how to remove the CMOS battery, and I have not tried it yet.

Comment: This option is only intended for compliance testing at OEMs. I’m sure the description text said something similar. [See also here.](https://www.eightforums.com/installation-setup/39857-confusing-whql-bios-setting-gigabyte-mainboards-post335692.html#post335692)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Erasing the CMOS memory worked. I did not remove the battery to do so, either. I downloaded my motherboard's manual from the internet and found the pins that let me reset the CMOS (this is an MSI motherboard, they were labeled as JBAT1). Connecting both pins with a paperclip was enough to fix the problem. Afterwards I plugged my computer back in and was welcomed with a "BIOS settings have been reset to default" style message.

If you ever do this yourself, make sure to completely power off and unplug your computer, then wait a few minutes. Some motherboards even have a button to reset the CMOS, or come with a jumper specially designed to do this, but a paperclip works just fine, even taking out the battery (if you're able to, because I wasn't) can work. Also, thank you @Neil for your help.